# Multiple If Statements Cancelling each-other out? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, salesforce

I've been having some trouble with a piece of code that requires multiple lines of "if" logic to handle the functionality.

two of these if statements do the same thing, and it seems to me are some how cancelling each other out.

```
function visibleCheck() {

    var target = document.getElementById('contentType').val();

    if (target != "BYOC - Document to Exam") {
        document.getElementById('VideoMinutes').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else document.getElementById('VideoMinutes').style.display = 'none';

    if ((target != "Custom Production - Avatar") {
        document.getElementById('Questions').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else document.getElementById('Questions').style.display = 'none';

    if ((target != "Custom Production - Video") {
        document.getElementById('Questions').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else document.getElementById('Questions').style.display = 'none';

}
```

The First if statement runs fine. The second doesn't appear to run at all. The third one runs fine.

If I re-order the second and third one swapping places, the new second one will not work.

If I use the or operator "||" and combine the statements it doesn't work at all.

The third statement always works regardless of the conditions for the if statement.

If I make the second and third both if or statements then neither work.

Any ideas?

I am using this on a visualforce page within salesforce if that makes any difference.

Comment: Have you looked into using `else if`statements?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I hadn't considered it, because there's already three, and there may be more. Do you think it could make a difference?

Comment: And/or a `switch()` ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)) statement.

Comment: Personal suggestion: wrap your `else` cases in `{}` just like you do the `if` case. Makes things cleaner and catches certain bugs. The other thing is what do you mean the second one "doesn't appear to run at all"?

Comment: A basic look at the debug console would show you several glaring errors in your code.  You need to learn the first elemental steps of debugging BEFORE bringing your code here.  For one, there's no `.val()` method on a DOM element (that's a jQuery method, not a DOM method) and you have mismatched parentheses.  Both of these errors would be shown in the debug console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, note that DOMElements do not have the `val()` method, that's only on jQuery objects. You should use the `value` property.

Secondly, the logic is flawed as the execution for the `Questions` elements can flow through multiple contradicting conditions. Try this:

```
function visibleCheck() {
    var target = document.getElementById('contentType').value;

    if (target != "BYOC - Document to Exam") {
        document.getElementById('VideoMinutes').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('VideoMinutes').style.display = 'none';
    }

    if (target != "Custom Production - Avatar" && target != "Custom Production - Video") {
        document.getElementById('Questions').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('Questions').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

As you've tagged this with jQuery, here's a simplified jQuery version:

```
function visibleCheck() {
    var target = $('#contentType').val();
    $('#VideoMinutes').toggle(target != 'BYOC - Document to Exam');
    $('#Questions').toggle(target != "Custom Production - Avatar" && target != "Custom Production - Video");
}
```

Comment: I had actually copied an older version of the code, but your simplified version works great, thanks!